# How to make observable collection binded with check boxes update first before checkbox Changes event in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Let me explain the question.

I have an observable collection of type FilterTags (Where FilteredTags is a class, have a property called "isChecked").
Now my check boxes are binded with this observable collection. It is a two way binding, so when i check a check box, the change is reflected in the collection.
Also the checkbox has a check changed event. The  problem is the checkchanged event called before the changes are updated in the collection.

I want the collection to be updated first so that i can use it in the checkboxchanged function. Is there any way I can do that???

Comment: What are you doing in the check changed event? Something to update the UI elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try do not use subscribing to events in code behind under user control. Try design project according to a MVVM pattern. You can find some information [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430869%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try somting like this.
Fire a Event wenn the Update is ready.

```
public event EventHandler SaveCompleted;
```

...

```
_ctx.SubmitChanges((so) => {
        if (SaveCompleted != null) SaveCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
        InvalidateCommands();

    }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this for a text box to force the model's value to be updated when the text changes, maybe it can help you (try running this at the top of your event handler):

```
var expression = this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
if (expression != null)
    expression.UpdateSource();
```